# How to mock data access in private methods

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I would like to ask how can I use rhino mocks with in the next example:

```
   Public Class CustomerService 
    {
      Public void Register()
     {
         Action1();
         Action2();
     }

    private action1 ()
     {
       //this is a call to other dll.
       var isExist = _dataComponentService.CheckIfUserExist(userName);
     } 
   private action2()
     {
       //do some more work...
       // Call to dataComponentService. write some data in the database....
     }
    }
```

this is only an example for the real code I need to update. 
The current unit tests are making a real call to the database service.
I would like to write a unit tests that checks the behavior in the public Register() with out needing to make a real call to the database service.

is it possible to mock a call to other component that is located in private method without needing to re-write the hole service?

thank you in advanced

Ori

Comment: You should use Dependency Injection to provide `dataComponentService` object to `CustomerService` class. I recommend Constructor Injection. During application runtime `dataComponentService` is set as real database-access instance, but in test scenario you can use mock object. There are a lot of articles on the Web about DI with unit test, for example Mark Seemann's blog: [link](http://blog.ploeh.dk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do some dependency injection to get your mock into your class-under-test (for more information on DI, check out [this article](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) by Martin Fowler). First your 'dataComponentService' class will need to implement an interface:

```
public interface IDataComponentService
{
    boolean CheckIfUserExist(String user);
}
```

Then you can inject classes that implement that interface into your CustomerService class by adding an appropriate constructor:

```
public class CustomerService 
{
    private IDataComponentService _dataComponentService

    // This constructor allows you to inject your dependency into the class
    public CustomerService(IDataComponentService dataComponentService)
    {
        _dataComponentService = dataComponentService;
    }

    Public void Register()
    {
        Action1();
        Action2();
    }

    private action1 ()
    {
        //this is a call to other dll.
        var isExist = _dataComponentService.CheckIfUserExist(userName);
    } 

    private action2()
    {
       //do some more work...
       // Call to dataComponentService. write some data in the database....
    }
}
```

Now, in your test code your tests you can create a mock of an IDataComponentService...

```
var dataComponentServiceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataComponentService>(); 
//add mock's behavior here...
```

... and pass it into your class-under-test thus...

```
var objUt = new CustomerService(dataComponentServiceMock);
objUt.Register();
// check method calls to the mock here...
```

Comment: When you write a test you test the public methods. in this case I make a call to other service in a private method.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.  When you write a test you test the public methods. in this case I make a call to other service in a private method. the question is how can I stub a response to other service so the code can continu with out braking when it is in private method?  in order to test an Expect a behavior that is at the end of the private method.

Comment: Is the service you're talking about the _dataComponentService service? If so you can add the behavior to the mock. If you want to test what's going on inside the private methods I'm not sure how you can unless they perform some action that you can test for. Alternatively you can make the methods internal and expose them to your test library as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Comment: I think I will make it easier if I will just write a test that goes along all the code in the private method. is it possible to Stub an action inside the private method?  let say something like dataComponentServiceMock.Stub(x=>x.GetInfo).IgnoreAarguments().Return(SomeObject)  thank you

Comment: From looking at your code the only method call you make inside a private method is _dataComponentService.CheckIfUserExist(userName), and you can mock that using the technique in my answer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your question raises some suspicions with me.
One : A unit test is not a unit test if it is performing database access. If it is doing the database access it is more like an integration test.
Two : You should rely more on dependency injection and start to program towards interfaces instead of objects. This would mean that you inject the interface that you have to define for _datacomponentservice

On top of this. Even though you have a private method. You can relax it perhaps to protected and make it virtual. If it is virtual you can make a special test version of the class where you implement the protected member differently.

Many people are defining many private methods, but I find that sometimes this will block the future developments and I' rather have them be protected than private. Because you never know how the future will be. I use for instance .NET reflector to browse through microsofts code for say a combobox, wanting to make it more flexible. I have a hell of a time sometimes to do this because some methods and classes even are just not accessible in derived classes.